# Blessing children together or individually?

Tags: shabbat, blessing, children-parenting, birchas-kohanim

When I was a child, my parents would bless my siblings and me on Erev Shabbos. The formulation that they used was "Yesimcha Elokim kEphraim v'ch'Menashe" for each son and "Yesimech Elokim kSarah, Rivka, Rachel, V'Leah" for each daughter, and then they would say the kohen's blessing "yevarechicha..." once for everyone together.

Usually when I have seen other families blessing their children, they do it quietly so it is difficult for others to hear, but I believe that they say the kohen blessing separately for each child. Is this the typical practice?

Comment: AFAIK yes. No source (yet), so I'm not posting this as an answer (yet).

Comment: @msh210 Any source now (besides yourself and the two comment upvotes agreeing with you)?

Comment: There's no way to downvote a comment. For all I know, there may be dozens of people who disagree with my comment above. `:-)` In any event, no, no source now. Sorry.

Comment: @msh210 That's why I ask for a source :)

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers